# JAVA : possible loss of precision

Tags: java, double, precision, floating

I wrote the following method in JAVA :

```
public static float surface(float r)
    {
        return(4*Math.PI*Math.pow(r,2));
    }
```

when I run the class, I got the following error :

```
possible loss of precision
required: float; found: double
```

I saw in the doc that Math.pow needs `double` to work. What do I have to do if I need to work with `float` ?

To test, I tried to following method, which is giving the same error :

```
public static float surface(float r)
    {
        return(4*Math.PI*r*r);
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to type cast `double` to `float`.

```
public static float surface(float r)
{
    return (float)(4*Math.PI*Math.pow(r,2));
}
```

Please look into [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

`Math.PI` is defined as `double`. Since you're returning a `float`, there has to be a conversion from `double` to `float` "anywhere" - which is a possible loss of precision.

Edit: BTW: consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` or `float`. If you use "BigDecimal" and "float" as keywords for a search in the web, you'll find many articles dealing with this topic explaining the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.